# "fatal error: 'src/core/lib/surface/event_string.h' file not found" cloud_firestore with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

When creating a new flutter app and integrating cloud firestore, I seem to be getting this error.

There was an issue with podfiles... I've tried different branches of flutter (master, dev, beta).

The docs for the cloud_firestore: ^0.9.13+1 package are different from the docs on firestore's official console seemingly regarding the handling of Podfiles.

Sometimes the errors are directed at signing in xcode and the project_id. Even when starting over, as soon as I try to integrate firestore the app breaks with this missing 'event_string.h' file.

```
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           69.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET gRPC-Core OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/joey/Code/dart/spry_up/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/surface/completion_queue.cc:41:10: fatal error: 'src/core/lib/surface/event_string.h' file not found
    #include "src/core/lib/surface/event_string.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
```

I'm not sure where to go for assistance. I've rebuilt the app 3 times already.

Comment: it demands [event_string.h](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/surface/event_string.h)... probably even the whole gRPC.

Comment: @MartinZeitler By this, are you saying I should add this myself? I'm at a loss where the initial problem is...

Answer (score 0):

please try this edits in Podfile Code needs to be added or edited are marked with "** ...... **"

```
target 'Runner' do
  ** use_frameworks!  **
```

........ ......

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
          ** config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0' **
        end
      end
    end
```

delete your Podfile.lock and try

Comment: This did not work. It if matters, I chose Objective-C as my ios language when creating the flutter project in IntelliJ IDEA. Still the same error, now with the "Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:" error of which I'm fairly sure should not be the issue... Could be wrong...